# Facing problem in retrieving value from multidimentional array through loop in php

Tags: php

I have retrieved a multi-dimensional array through api but I am unbale to retrieve values from array

Please check the code below

```
<div class="container">
 <h2>Our  Partners/ Our Clients</h2>
   <section class="customer-logos slider">
  <?php for ($i=0; $i <count($response) ; $i++) 
   { 
   ?>
       <div class="slide">
       <img src="<?php echo $response['urlToImage'][$i]; ?>">
       </div>
     <?php }?>

    </section>
</div>
```

> Using above code i am unable to fetch data properly
>
> below is the array from which i need value

```
Array
(
 [title] => Array
    (
        [0] => Saudi energy minister: We'd work with anyone interested in 
   balancing the oil market - CNBC
        [1] => Gurley, Rams run through Cowboys, advance with 30-22 victory 
 - Fox News
        [2] => NFL Conference Semifinals (Call It That!): Foles Hasn't Been 
  Tested Like This, Chargers’ Fatal Flaw - Sports Illustrated

    )

[description] => Array
    (
        [0] => Saudi Energy Minister Khalid al-Falih told CNBC on Sunday that his country "will work with all interested producers who want to bring stability to the market ... OPEC plus and anybody else who would like to do it with us.
        [1] => The high-flying Los Angeles Rams kept the ball firmly on the ground, and they ran straight past the Dallas Cowboys for a breakthrough playoff victory.
        [2] => Also, the desperate scramble to win the press conference, what the eight conference semifinal coaches were when they were hired, and the latest coaching fashion trend. Plus, an encore performance from The Mountain Goats!

    )

[url] => Array
    (
        [0] => https://www.cnbc.com/2019/01/13/saudi-energy-minister-on-work-with-oil-producers-to-balance-market.html
        [1] => https://www.foxnews.com/sports/gurley-rams-run-through-cowboys-advance-with-30-22-victory
        [2] => https://www.si.com/nfl/2019/01/13/playoffs-patriots-chargers-eagles-saints-conference-semifinals-divisional-round-coach-hirings

    )

[urlToImage] => Array
    (
        [0] => https://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2018/06/22/105288796-GettyImages-981021686.1910x1000.jpg
        [1] => https://static.foxnews.com/foxnews.com/content/uploads/2019/01/rams-cowboys-gurley.jpg
        [2] => https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https://cdn-s3.si.com/s3fs-public/2019/01/12/football-things-conference-semifinals.jpg&w=1200&h=628&c=sc&poi=face&q=85

    )
```

Comment: Are you trying to iterate only over the images?

Comment: What  about `<?php for ($i=0; $i <count($response['urlToImage']) ; $i++)` ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I assume you're trying to iterate over the images URL's only, consider the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Our Partners/ Our Clients</h2>
    <section class="customer-logos slider">
        <?php if (isset($response['urlToImage'])) : ?>
            <?php foreach ($response['urlToImage'] as $imageUrl): ?>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="<?= $imageUrl; ?>">
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </section>
</div>
```